# Accessing ReactJS front end with Flask Backend from another device in the same network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flask, docker-compose

I have a reactJS front end and Flask backend running on a linux device on ports 3000 and 5000 respectively. Both are containerized and orchestrated using docker-compose and works well. Now I am trying to access these from another device in the same network. I do not have an issue accessing my Flask api's from the connected device. "http://<IP_OF_LINUX_MACHINE>:5000" works, but "http://<IP_OF_LINUX_MACHINE>:3000" do not load anything. Loading "http://<IP_OF_LINUX_MACHINE>:3000" on chrome just shows React favicon icon on the tab. There is no information on inspect as well. I tried the following:

1. On Linux machine "sudo ufw allow 3000"
2. In React App package.json added {"start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 && PORT=3000 && react-scripts start"}
3. On the windows device (other device in network), enabled inbound rules for Nodejs.

What am I missing?

Comment: A few days ago, I was using google cloud console to do just the exact same process. I almost gave up but after a few minutes of leaving it alone, it finally loaded. I think the favicon is a good things XD. Just give it some few minute ^ ^

Comment: I don't build Front Ends and first time using ReactJS. Not sure if I should switch to some other framework. I am new to JS as well. Working with React has been an annoying experience as a beginner. Any recommendations?

Comment: How does you `docker-compose.yml` file look like? I wonder if port 3000 is not exposed or made accessible outside the container

Comment: I have exposed the ports on dockerfile. Still not sure what the root cause was, but a fresh image build and restarting the containers fixed my issue.